# How can I generate a Facebook User Access Token from my API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve user leads via the Facebook Graph API. The problem is that this happens over an API and not via a user interface. Are there any alternative ways of generating the User Access Token besides through the Facebook Login SDK?

I have tried to find ways to generate the User Access Token on my API, but couldn't find any relevant information.

Comment: No, you can not create the access token on your end. You could generate one using Graph API Explorer, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/, if that's enough for your requirements; or you will actually have to implement Facebook login yourself.